# Passing array of array elements to a function

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've been searching for an answer of this concept for a whole day and finally gave up and decided to ask it here.

Here's the concept:

I have a set of fields which are arrayed, I want that set of fields to be inside of array so that I can use a standard function for saving a module based on the fields involved and another param to check which to save.

Sample code:

*module1.php*

```
<?php
$i=0;
while($i<5){
?>
<input type="text" name="field1[$i]" />
<input type="text" name="field2[$i]" />
<input type="text" name="field3[$i]" />
<?php
$i++;
}
?>
<input type="button" name="process"
onclick="checkFields(['field1', 'field2', 'field3'], 'module1');" />
<script>
    function checkFields(f, m){
        var fn = f.length;
        alert(fn); //Output is 3
        for(i=0; i<fn; i++){
            var nfn = f[i].length; //Here's where it's not working
            alert(nfn); //Output should be 5
        }
    }
</script>
```

So, that part with comment is the thing I can't figure how to do, I tried using `getElementById`, `getElementsByName` but it's not working.

Or is there any possibility that I can pass an array of elements like this: `array(field1, field2, field3)` to a function?

Edit: I added a while loop statement to make the concept more comprehensive.

Comment: **arrayed set of fields**? "field1[]" or "field1", it's just a name and not really array of fields.

Comment: it's still field1[] since that field will have multiple value. Like it is inside a while loop. I'll edit my question again.

Comment: in html, it's still just a name. you can have multiple fields with same name e.g. 2 fields with same name "field1[]", or 2 fields with different names "field1[0]", "field1[1]". Remember there is no notion of array in html input fields, they are just a name with flexibility of same name duplicated multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function checkFields(f, m){
        var fn = f.length;
        alert(fn);
        for(i=0; i<=fn; i++){
            var nfn = f[i].length; //Here's where it's not working
            alert(nfn);
        }
    }
</script>
```

You should be applying the indexer on the f parameter, instead of the fn variable which is an integer.

Comment: Ooops, wait, that's not working either, I mean, I mistype it. Let me correct it.

Answer (score 0):

`fn` is the length of your array, not your array.  You should be using `f`

Change...

```
var nfn = fn[i].length; //Here's where it's not working
```

To...

```
var nfn = f[i];
```

Also, you will find that the `for` loop will fail, as `i` will reach `fn` but the array stops at `fn-1`

So change...

```
for(i=0; i<=fn; i++){
```

To...

```
for(i=0; i<fn; i++){
```

Comment: I mistype that. Actually, that will not work since the f's value is in string already, I just tried to make the concept easier to understand.

Comment: It's still that question, just that the f's value is already a string since, if you want to get an element's array length it should be pass as the element name without a `'` like for example, I should pass field1[] as `field1` not `'field1'`. It's just that, I want to make the passing of field with an indefinite number of fields 'cause it's a same concept with different number of fields for other modules.

Comment: Do you mean something like `document.getElementById(f[i]).length`?

Comment: Like I said, I tried that already but it's not working, it does not count the array length of the element.

Comment: Sorry, you're really not making any sense.  You started talking about an array of fields, now you're talking about arrays within arrays, but not giving any examples of what all these different arrays are.  I'm very close to giving up helping

Comment: Is `field1` the name of a global variable within your page, that holds an array of information? And the same for `field2` and `field3`?  If so, then you want to call your function with `checkFields([field1, field2, field3], 'module1');`

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted, you're last comment. I tried passing the elements name, but it's not outputting anything, like it have an error.

Comment: Sigh, so `field1` is not a javascript array, it's a hidden field. What **exactly** is the format of the information in the hidden fields that is generated by `field1[$i]`?

Comment: No, the field1[$i] will also have values from a user input... that I will save in the database that's why it is also indefinite...

Answer (score 0):

f[i] still points to just the incorrect input names. You don't really get access to the input field.

Do this:

```js
var inputName = f[i] + "[]";//remember the input name is field1[] and not field1.
var value = document.querySelector( "input[name='"+inputName+"']" ).value;
```

the value here is just the input text of the input field and not really an array. If you have multiple fields with the same name, then use `document.querySelectorAll` method to get all the input fields and then iterate to get the values one by one.

---

To help you understand better, consider these 2 options:

Option 1:

html:

```
<input name="field1[]" />
<input name="field1[]" />
```

access the value:

```
var inputFields = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='field1[]']");
var values = [];
for (var j = 0; j < inputFields.length; j++) {
    var val = inputFields[i].value;
    values.push(val);
}
```

Option 2:

html:

```
<input name="field1[0]" />
<input name="field1[1]" />
```

access the value:

```
var values = [];
var j = 0;
var inputField;
while (true) {
    var inputField = document.querySelector("input[name='field1[" + j + "]']");
    if (!inputField) break;
    values.push(inputField.value);
    j++;
}
```

Note that, in option 1, there are multiple fields with the same "name" and in option 2, there are multiple fields with unique names.